# What does $\{0,1\}^J$ mean in math?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

"When accommodating customer choice behavior, we assume that the arriving customer chooses product j with probability $P_{t,j}(u)$, where $u \in \mathcal{U} \equiv \{0,1\}^J$ corresponds to the characteristic vector of the set of products currently being offered;"

What does $\{0,1\}^J$ mean?

Comment: I could take a guess. But what is $J$ here?

Comment: Generally in math, $A^B$ is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. Thus this is basically a vector of length $|J|$ whose entries are either zero or one.

Comment: my guess would be a sparse vector with dimension J - being the number of products.

Comment: "where $J$ is the number of products," so it is a constant.

Comment: @mdslt yep - common in recommendation systems. With a matrix of `users x products`.

Comment: This appears to be a quote from https://www.jstor.org/stable/24740543.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J$ represent the list of products. Let $j\in J$ represent a particular product (e.g. $j=$"iPhone"). Then $u_j=0$ probably means the person did not buy that product and $u_j=1$ probably means they did buy that product.

The space $\mathcal U=\{0,1\}^J$ would be the set of all binary vectors with $|J|$ components where $|J|$ is the total number of different products included in set $J$. It will just be a bunch of $|J|$-tuples with each having the form $(0,1,1,0,0,1,\ldots,0,1,1,0)$ with all possible arrangements of $0$'s and $1$'s included (and $|J|$ total digits in the list). I.e. $u=(1,1,1,\ldots, 1,1,1)$ means they bought every single product and all zeros implies they bought none of the products (presumably that's the interpretation).

It's just
$$\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\times\cdots\times\{0,1\}$$
with the appropriate number of repetitions of $\{0,1\}$. This is called a "Cartesian product" usually. where it just means you pick one value from each set in the product and combine them separated by commas encapsulated in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a cartesian product, i.e.,

$u\in\{0,1\}^J$ iff $u=(u_j)_{j=1}^J$ with $u_i\in\{0,1\}$.

For generals sets, $R^D$ is the set of functions $f:D\to R$, which is equivalent to the definition given above.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to describe a vector of $1$'s and $0$'s. For example, if $J = 3$, you would have $$\mathcal U = \{ (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1) \}.$$
The interpretation of, let's say, $u = (1,0,1)$ would be that customer chooses products 1 and 3, but not 2.

You might be familiar with notation $\mathbb R^3$, which would be the set of vectors of type $(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$. This is completely analogous.

As others noted, you could interpret it as the set of functions $u\colon J\to \{0,1\}$, but that's just a different way to describe the same thing, since for some $j\in J$, if $u(j) = 1$, the customer chooses product $j$, and if $u(j) = 0$, the customer doesn't choose the product $j$.